# Check success of indexeddb createIndex

Tags: javascript, web, storage, offline, indexeddb

I'm noticing a decent delay between being able to retrieve results and creation and population of an IndexedDB objectStore.  I suspect that the indexing is still running after a large number of "put"s are done, but I'm not sure how to measure each part (createobjectStore, createIndex), and report back.

**Is there a simple way to check the success of the index being created?**

```
request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
    var db = e.target.result;
    var partsStore = db.createObjectStore("parts", { keyPath: "classID", autoIncrement: true });
     partsStore.createIndex("description", "description", { unique: false });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just listen for the success event of `request`. The success event is not raised until the upgrade function completes.

```
var request = indexedDB.open(...);
request.onupgradeneeded = function() {
  // create indices and whatever
  store.createIndex(...);
};

request.onsuccess = function() {
  console.log('this shows up after the upgrade completes');
};
```